# Chrome extension development: chrome.storage.local vs Indexeddb

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, indexeddb, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am currently developing a digital wallet application as a chrome extension and trying to figure out what I should use as my persistent storage layer: **chrome.storage.local** or **indexedDb**. I have looked into other similar open-source projects, and it seems like most use the former instead of the latter.

I would like to understand if there is any advantage in using one over the other. Currently, the reasons I lean towards using **chrome.storage.local** are:

- It is suggested as the storage API in the official chrome extension docs
- It is persistent across app restarts. (Indexeddb also appears to be but I haven't found it being mentioned as persistent storage explicitly in any documentation, so I'm not sure)
- Both are async
- Straightforward API (unlike indexeddb)

I understand that my use-cases and data shape is likely a big factor: As far as my app is concerned

- I am storing simple JSON types (Strings, numbers, bool, objects, arrays)
- Arrays of objects can grow arbitrarily long, e.g. storing list of addresses or transaction history. (This is really the main reason that makes me think if IndexedDb would provide any advantage)

Based on the above, is there any reason that one would serve my application better than the other? Is there anything else I should take into consideration? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Chrome and in Firefox, IndexedDB used by an extension is persistent. In Chrome it's unlimited even without adding `"unlimitedStorage"` to `"permissions"` so it uses global quota management, see [crbug.com/1209236](https://crbug.com/1209236). I've imported a dummy 40MB JSON (15MB compressed) and it worked. Safari WebExtensions specification is probably much less generous.

The reasons to use IndexedDB:

1. Non-string **keys** and **values** supported by the [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) (Map, Set, Date, RegExp, Blob, File, FileList, ArrayBuffer, ImageBitmap, ImageData, and [recently](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/structured-data.html#structuredserializeinternal) BigInt, Error) in addition to the basic JSON-compatible types offered by `chrome.storage.local` and `.sync` (string, number, boolean, null, and arrays/objects that recursively consist of these trivial types).
2. Storing and reading big or deeply nested objects may be easily 10 times faster or even more.
3. Checking for an existence of a key without reading its value.
4. Reading just the names of the keys without reading their values.
5. Indexing by several keys.
6. Dedicating an entire `object store` (or lots of them) per each array that  may grow or shrink unpredictably. This will be many times faster (maybe even 1000 if the array is big) than reading the entire array, modifying it, and writing back to a single key in `chrome.storage`.

IndexedDB of the extension can't be used in a content script directly, only via workarounds:

- Messaging. In Chrome ManifestV2 it's limited to JSON-compatible types so to transfer complex types you'll have to stringify them (slow) or convert the data via `new Response` into a `Blob`, feed it to URL.createObjectURL, send the resultant URL, revoke it after confirming the receipt. Chrome's ManifestV3 will support the structured clone algo for messages [soon](https://crbug.com/248548) but their implementation still stringifies the cloned data internally so it's bound to be slow with big amounts of data until they fix it.

  Firefox doesn't suffer from this restriction, AFAIK.
- iframe in the web page with `src` pointing to an html page of the extension exposed via `web_accessible_resources` in its manifest.json. This iframe (in Chrome) runs in the extension process so it'll have direct access to its storage, and it can use parent.postMessage, which supports structured clone algo, to send the result. To avoid interception by the page you should run your content script at [document_start](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time) to attach a listener in capturing mode before the page does and prevent its listeners from seeing the event:

  ```js
  // this script must be declared with "run-at": "document_start"
  const extensionOrigin = chrome.runtime.getURL('').slice(0, -1);
  window.addEventListener('message', e => {
    if (e.origin === extensionOrigin) {
      e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // hide from the page
      console.log(e); // process the event
    }
  }, true); // register in the first phase, "capture"
  ```

  It's not enough though! Sites can install a listener before the extension does because of a foundational security hole in the implementation of WebExtensions (observed in Chrome and Firefox) that allows pages to modify the environment of a newly created same-origin iframe or tab/window, see [crbug.com/1261964](https://crbug.com/1261964), so for sensitive extensions you'll have to implement very complicated workarounds until this hole is patched. Hopefully, ManifestV3 will provide a secure postMessage limited to the "isolated world" of content scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! It provides a lot of helpful context. 
1. It's not entirely clear that (a) 'unlimitedStorage' permission is not required and (b) indexedDb will persist with no risk of automatic eviction. Both things are discussed in the issue you mentioned and [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=680392&q=indexeddb%20chrome.storage&can=2), but still unclear about the resolution by the chrome team.
2. Is there any reason that chrome doesn't mention using indexedDb for extension development in **any** official documentation?

Comment: I appreciate the advantages you've mentioned! It makes indexedDb a serious consideration for our project. The lack of official documentation on it is what make me a bit wary.

Comment: Looks like even Chromium team doesn't know what happens with and without unlimitedStorage permission so you'll have to investigate it yourself in various browsers.

Comment: this seems pretty clear that `unlimitedStorage` is, in fact, needed: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/storage-and-cookies#storage-persistence

Comment: We can't trust this documentation because it's maintained by people who aren't core developers. Per https://crbug.com/1209236 unlimitedStorage doesn't yet help against eviction under pressure, so specifically for IndexedDB it's pointless. There were also no related commits [for 4 years](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/q/unlimitedStorage+status:merged).

Answer (score 0):

If you want your extension support Safari in the future and your extension needs to store a big data, don't use indexedDB.

unlimitedStorage permission is supported in Safari 16, but it's only for storage.local, for the indexDB, both Safari 16 and 17 have a limitation about 1.5GB.